# DSharp+ static void main() won't load

Tags: c#, exception, program-entry-point, dsharp+

I think I might need help with my main method, it gives me an unhandled exception whenever I try to load my Discord bot, here's what the exception says: `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Type must be a class, which cannot be abstract or static. Parameter name: t'`

Here's the full stack trace: ***" at DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextExtension.RegisterCommands(Type t)\r\n at DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextExtension.RegisterCommandsT\r\n at Arthur_Bot.Bot.RunAsync() in C:\Users\bvgof\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Arthur-Bot\Arthur-Bot\Bot.cs:line 54\r\n at Arthur_Bot.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\bvgof\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Arthur-Bot\Arthur-Bot\Program.cs:line 8"***

Program.cs:

```
namespace Arthur_Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bot = new Bot();
            bot.RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Bot.cs:

```
using Arthur_Bot.Commands;
using DSharpPlus;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext;
using DSharpPlus.EventArgs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Arthur_Bot
{
    public class Bot
    {
        public DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }

        public CommandsNextExtension Commands { get; private set; }

        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var json = string.Empty;

            using (var fs = File.OpenRead("config.json"))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
                json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var configJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigJson>(json);

            var config = new DiscordConfiguration
            {
                Token = configJson.Token,
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                AutoReconnect = true,
                MinimumLogLevel = LogLevel.Debug
            };

            Client = new DiscordClient(config);

            Client.Ready += OnClientReady;

            var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration
            {
                StringPrefixes = new string[] { configJson.Prefix },
                EnableMentionPrefix = true,
                EnableDefaultHelp = false,
                EnableDms = false,
                CaseSensitive = true,
                DmHelp = false
            };

            Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);

            Commands.RegisterCommands<FunCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<EconomyCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<ModeratorCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<ProfileCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<HelpCommands>();

            await Client.ConnectAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task OnClientReady(DiscordClient client, ReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            client = Client;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's going on, can I please have some help?

Comment: Could you show the complete stack trace rather than just the message? That's likely to help us to work out the problem.

Comment: is this what you mean?
> Arthur-Bot.dll!Arthur_Bot.Program.Main(string[] args = {string[0]}) Line 8 C#

Comment: Wait, I think this is the stack trace: "   at DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextExtension.RegisterCommands(Type t)\r\n   at DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextExtension.RegisterCommands[T]()\r\n   at Arthur_Bot.Bot.RunAsync() in C:\\Users\\bvgof\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Arthur-Bot\\Arthur-Bot\\Bot.cs:line 54\r\n   at Arthur_Bot.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Users\\bvgof\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Arthur-Bot\\Arthur-Bot\\Program.cs:line 8"

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. It looks like that's in `Bot.RunAsync`, which I assume is your code... but which you haven't shown us. We can't really help you without seeing your code.

Comment: oh! Sorry forgot about that, lemme edit it so it shows it

Comment: Right, well *one* of those `RegisterCommands` calls is using an abstract or static type. Line 54 is the one with the problem. The error message is pretty specific about it - look at line 54, look at the type you're specifying, and note that it should be non-static and concrete, and a class...

Comment: thx! I fixed it by deleting the classes with no code in them!